# Unambiguous Context free Grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, context-free-grammar, language-theory, context-free-language

I was reading through Context Free Grammar, and I came across ambiguous grammar. If the language produced by CFG has more then 1 parse tree, then CFG is an ambiguous grammar. 
Is there any way by which I can find out or prove that the grammar is Unambiguous. In general I can test some language produced by CFG and check whether more than 1 parse tree is generated from that language, to show that grammar is ambiguous. But how do I check or prove that give CFG is unambiguous?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2320/how-to-prove-that-a-grammar-is-unambiguous and http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7518/how-to-show-that-given-language-is-unambiguous should help.

Answer (score 2):

The ambiguity problem for CFGs is undecidable in the general case. However, there are some ways to check whether the language is *likely* to be ambiguous. Check [this article](http://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/papers/ambiguity/journal.pdf) if you want the theory of it; for something more practical, consider [this](http://www.brics.dk/grammar/) or [this](http://www2.tcs.ifi.lmu.de/~mlange/cfganalyzer/index.html).